# Bootstrap with jQuery and Popper.js (svelte)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, svelte, rollupjs, popper.js

I wanted to add Bootstrap 4 with jQuery and Popper.js to RollupJS.

How to add them to the bundler?

I'm also using Svelte rollup template.

Comment: Please provide more informations about what you did and what errors occured.

Comment: I don't have any errors but I have no idea about adding Bootstrap Javascript requirements.

Comment: Moreover, I have no idea what is wrong with people that they do -1 to my question.

Comment: Well idea is that you show us what you did and what errors you get and we'll try to check code and suggest solution. If you don't know where to start and what to do someone needs to take entire project and do work for you and that is out of scope of SO platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are using the default Svelte Rollup template (probably through `npx degit sveltejs/template`), and you would like to add support for Bootstrap in your project.

If that's the case, then I believe it should be ...

```
npm i bootstrap
npm i jquery
npm i popper.js
npm i --save-dev rollup-plugin-css-only
```

In your `rollup.config.js`, add:

`import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';`

at the top with the rest of the imports.  Also, in the `plugins` array, add:

```
plugins: [
  ...
  production && terser(),
  css({ output: 'public/build/extra.css'})
],
```

In `src/main.js` add imports for:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

And in `public/index.html` add a link to the rollup generated extra.css:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/extra.css'>
```

That at least gets bootstrap working for me through rollup, although I'm not using jquery or popper.js.  In fact, I found this question when searching for the *opposite* problem -- How to use rollup with bootstrap *without* requiring jquery and popper.js.

Remember, you'll need to restart your dev server since auto-reload won't work for changes to rollup.config.js.

Comment: Then add this to your App.svelte

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>

If you see a green success you're good.

This response is excellent and deserves more than 2 votes.

Comment: Just a tip to all future readers: in *Bootstrap 5* the `popper.js` npm package has been replaced with `@popperjs/core`

Comment: Gave one up to Scott, however - there is still clear answer - how do you add it? Will popper be compiled into the bundle? Do I have to include it in my index.html handish? How? I need to include popper for BS5 in my Svelte-App.

Comment: Just found this one after reading the thread https://dev.to/gokayokyay/how-to-use-popper-with-svelte-in-a-sveltish-way-with-actions-2h02